# Android Google login: refresh expired id token

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I use google sign-in in my app:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

googleLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GET_TOKEN);
            }
        });
```

But after 1 hours idToken expires and i have to login again, but i want it to refresh idToken automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: use <code>silentSignIn</code> to get a new ID token each time? It will be cached or refreshed automatically for you ... https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#silentSignIn(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)

Comment: did you ever solve it?

Comment: no. too bad, cause I left the job and didn't have time to solve it for personal purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Here, wrote a blog post on it. Shows how to refresh tokens upon expiration. The example uses Retrofit and RxJava although you could use the concept even if you're not using RxJava https://thisbitofcode.com/refreshing-google-login-authentication-token-with-rxjava-and-retrofit-2/